# Is there a way to see which items are not categorized in magento?

Tags: magento

Is there a way to see which items are not categorized in magneto on the backend? I know I can pull a report but I was wondering if there was anything easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the free Enhanced Admin Grids extension, as the [github version](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids) allows to add a categories column on the products grid, for which it is optionally possible to filter on products that are not assigned to any category.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not seeing the "category" column just seeing the attributes... any idea?

Comment: Oh wait I installed the one from Magento Connect... How would I go about updating this to the GitHub version?

Comment: Answered to your github issues, sorry for any inconvenience !

Answer (score 0):

Not natively in the Magento backend.

You could run a simple SQL query against your database to grab a list of skus that aren't assigned to a category.

Something like this:

```
SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity
WHERE entity_id
NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM catalog_category_product)
```

Which will return a list of all skus not assigned to a category.  From there you can save the results to a CSV using your SQL program.